# Pacote Nuget Paint ou Assinatura Digital

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-forms, visual-studio-2017, nuget

Existe algum pacote nuget que permita fazer assinatura digital desenhando pela tela, ou mesmo um nuget que seja algo como um Paint onde se possa desenhar na tela e salvar como uma imagem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim. Tem alguns no mercado, mas eu recomendo um que já usei e sei que funciona bem: O [SignaturePad](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Controls.SignaturePad.Forms/3.0.0-preview-77).

Esse é um [componente open source](https://github.com/xamarin/SignaturePad) para coleta de assinaturas com Xamarin.Forms da própria Microsoft.

A declaração no XAML é bem simples:

> ```
> <controls:SignaturePad x:Name="signatureView"
>                        StrokeWidth="3"
>                        StrokeColor="White"
>                        Background="Black" />
> ```

E o componente já lhe entrega a imagem da assinatura como um `Stream` para você trabalhar como preferir, ou ainda como `Point[]`, caso você opte por armazenar a assinatura virtualmente e redesenhar em outro momento.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado, esse realmente vai me atender